# How many arc seconds is Sirius "spiralling motion" around Sirius B?

Tags: star-systems

I know that Sirius A and B orbit each other. I'd like to ask how large is their relative apparent motion in arc seconds, seen from Earth?

Answer (score 1):

From Sirius A to Sirius B on the sky is around 3 arcsec on average.

The separation between Sirius A and Sirius B actually varies from 3 to 11 arcseconds b/c of their orbital motion over a long period of time ([Here](https://florin.myip.org/blog/how-see-sirius-b)).

I believe you're referring to that. There's a lot of information (and even some graphs and diagrams) here: [Here](http://www.as.utexas.edu/white_dwarfs/wkshp_05/SiriusAB.pdf). The information on that website is sort of vague, but I think it'll be helpful in visualization.

Hope that helps!

Comment: not the separation between the two, the movement of Sirius A only

Comment: Sirius B has a wider orbit

Comment: looking at the link you included, http://www.as.utexas.edu/white_dwarfs/wkshp_05/SiriusAB.pdf, it looks like Sirius A has an orbit of 12 arc seconds in total, is that correct?

Comment: It looks like so. I think this source is slightly outdated, so I'm not putting too much reliance on it.

Comment: I read it wrong actually, it only goes to -0.5, so around 6.5 arc seconds.

Comment: Wait... Ha ha looks like I made the same mistake too. The graph goes down to -0.5, so it ranges to 6.5 arcsec. I was looking at the scale and thought that since it goes from -6 to +6 arcseconds, it has a range of 12 arcsec...